# Dell Optiplex 755 boots to Network by Default

Tags: pxe, dell-optiplex

I have a PXE Boot Server That is used for installing Debian and MemTest86+.

Suddenly my Dell Optiplex 755 starts to boot to PXE Boot by Default Even know Debian is Installed on the System.

I can boot to Debian By using F12.

For Some Reason I Cannot Access the Boot Sequence in the Bios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a lot of Optiplex's at work, you should be able to change this.

If you can get in to the BIOS, go to:

1. System Configuration
2. Integrated NIC
3. Either untick "UEFI Network Stack" or change the NIC to "enabled" rather then "Enabled w/PXE

[Screenshot of BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFWkh.jpg)